# Configure XPM Footprints to overwrite claims in Web 8

Tags: experience-manager, web8, ambient-data-framework, experience-optimization, footprint

Now that we use Microservices, I would like to understand where to configure claims forwarding for Footprints.
Like in similar questions asked prior to Web 8, I have Experience Optimization with a simple targeting rule which I would like to trigger based on XPM Footprint overwrites.
For instance setting the Session Length to 5 min to see the promotional content. 
So far none of my footprints are overwriting the context.

I added the footprint cartridge in the context microservice, configured it in cd_ambient_conf.xml, as well as whitelisted all IPs (this is for a demo server),  enabled all claims in GloballyAcceptedClaims. Enabled TAFContext cookie, and the ClaimStore .Net processor, just in case.

ADF is configured ok in the DXA 1.5 staging site, claims are set correctly and I can trigger XO promotions via XPM Persona just fine, as well as through browsing behavior and device detection. Only Footprints do not work.

`SmartTarget.xml` has the right prefixes setup. `trigger_types.xml` has the right triggers, I verified the prefix and claims names there, and made sure they correspond to the config in SiteEdit Editor.

I configured the context engine claims forwarding in `cd_ambient_conf.xml` also, by adding `taf:request:headers` and `taf:request:full_url` in the ForwardedClaims element:

```
<ForwardedClaims>
  <Claim Uri="taf:request:headers" />
  <Claim Uri="taf:request:full_url" />
</ForwardedClaims>
```

Do I need the same ADF config on the context service in the DXA site (last time I tried, the site was not loading), and on the XO query microservice? Should Cartridges be installed and configured in staging site and XO microservice also?

Here is `cd_ambient_conf.xml` in the Context microservice:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <Configuration Version="8.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
<Security OAuthEnabled="false">
    <RequestValidator>com.sdl.web.oauth.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator</RequestValidator>

    <!--Ambient data framework claims forwarding is enabled for the requests coming from white listed IP addresses.-->
    <WhiteList>
        <IPAddresses>
            <Ip>0.0.0.0-255.0.0.0</Ip>
            <Ip>127.0.0.1</Ip>
        </IPAddresses>
    </WhiteList>
    <GloballyAcceptedClaims>
        <Claim Uri="taf:session:preview:preview_session"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:browser"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:recurringvisitor"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:os"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:searchquery"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:session:lifetime"/>
        <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:refererdomain"/>

     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:date" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:coords" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:city" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:country" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:instore" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:weather:current" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:gender" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:age" />         
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:customer_value_code" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:offer_category" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:journey_segment" />        
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:customer_segment" />              
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:customer_order_total" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:customer_value_score" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:customer_wealth" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:days_since_last_order" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:spend_change" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:social_reach" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:flickr_id" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:segmentation:segment" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayHeight" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayWidth" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:inputDevices" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:mobile" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:model" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:orientation" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelDensity" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelRatio" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:tablet" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:vendor" />    

    <Claim Uri="taf:request:headers" />
    <Claim Uri="taf:request:full_url" />
    </GloballyAcceptedClaims>


    <!-- Built-in authentication server's configuration. -->
    <AuthenticationServer>
        <SharedSecret>sample_passphrase</SharedSecret>
    </AuthenticationServer>

    <!-- Rules definition for read/write shielding of services. -->
    <Rules Enabled="false"/>
</Security>
<!-- Excluded Paths -->

<ExcludedPaths>
    <!--
       <Path>/token.svc</Path>
    -->
</ExcludedPaths>
<Cartridges>

    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml" Category="SYSTEM"/>
    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="session_cartridge_conf.xml" />
    <Cartridge File="smarttarget_cartridge_conf.xml" />     
    <Cartridge File="defaultclaims_cartridge_conf.xml" />
    <Cartridge File="audiencemanager_cartridge_conf.xml" />             

    <Cartridge File="cwd_engine_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="cx_ambient_cartridge.xml" />


    <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>


</Cartridges>

<!-- Cookies settings -->

  <Cookies>        
      <Cookie Type="ADF" Name="TAFContext" />
  </Cookies>


<!-- The claim store provider that will be used. -->
<!-- For Java -->
<!--<ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.providers.JavaClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>-->
<!-- For .NET -->
<ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.providers.DotNetClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok apparently we need claims to be declared both in the `<ForwardedClaims>` and `<GloballyAcceptedClaims>` in the **staging site's** `cd_ambient_conf.xml`.

Here is a working config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Configuration Version="8.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">


<ExcludedPaths>
<!-- commented to enable preview of new images
       <Path>/media</Path>
       -->
<Path>/content</Path>
<Path>/Content</Path>
<Path>/system</Path>
</ExcludedPaths>

 <ForwardedClaims CookieName="TAFContext">
    <Claim Uri="taf:session:preview:preview_session"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:browser"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:recurringvisitor"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:os"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:searchquery"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:session:lifetime"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:refererdomain"/>

     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:date" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:coords" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:city" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:country" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:instore" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:weather:current" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:gender" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:age" />               
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:segmentation:segment" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:socialchannel:preferred" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayHeight" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayWidth" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:inputDevices" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:mobile" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:model" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:orientation" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelDensity" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelRatio" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:tablet" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:vendor" />        

    <Claim Uri="taf:request:cookies" /> 
    <Claim Uri="taf:request:headers" />
    <Claim Uri="taf:request:full_url" />
 </ForwardedClaims>

 <Security>
  <GloballyAcceptedClaims CookieName="TAFContext">
    <Claim Uri="taf:session:preview:preview_session"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:browser"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:recurringvisitor"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:os"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:searchquery"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:session:lifetime"/>
    <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:refererdomain"/>

     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:date" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:coords" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:city" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:country" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:instore" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:geolocation:weather:current" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:gender" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:age" />                  
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:segmentation:segment" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:socialchannel:preferred" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayHeight" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:displayWidth" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:inputDevices" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:mobile" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:model" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:orientation" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelDensity" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:pixelRatio" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:tablet" />
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:context:device:vendor" />        

    <Claim Uri="taf:request:cookies" /> 
    <Claim Uri="taf:request:headers" />
    <Claim Uri="taf:request:full_url" />
</GloballyAcceptedClaims>
</Security>

<!-- Cookies settings -->
<Cookies>
     <!-- <CookieClaim DefaultValue="true" Name="CookieClaim"/>
      <Cookie Type="Tracking" Name="myTrackingCookie" Path="/"/>
      <Cookie Type="Session" Name="mySessionCookie" Path="/"/>-->
      <Cookie Type="ADF" Name="TAFContext" />
  </Cookies>

  <!-- The claim store provider that will be used. -->
  <!-- For Java -->
  <!--              <ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.providers.JavaClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>-->
<!-- For .NET -->
    <ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.providers.DotNetClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>
</Configuration>
```

For footprints to work you also need the right IP range whitelisted, and enable the footprint cartridge in the Content microservice's `cd_ambient_conf.xml`

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two parts to the forwarding of claims: the client needs to know which claims to attempt to forward (ForwardedClaims section) and the server needs to know which claims to accept (GloballyAcceptedClaims section). And of course some more supporting configuration such as the whitelist for IP ranges.

It looks like you have configured the GloballyAcceptedClaims section correctly on the 'server' (context service), but you are missing the ForwardedClaims section on the 'client' (your website). If you add the claims in there, the forwarding should start working.

Comment: I had the forwardedclaims on the website but was missing them also in globalacceptedclaims

Comment: If you were missing them in the service, that's fine. But I don't believe you need that section on your website.

Comment: I know it sounds odd, but I just tested again, if I remove the GloballyAcceptedClaims from the staging site, claims forwarding stops working. Paul A. from R&D actually made the config change for me to fix the issue.

Comment: That IS odd -- I've never had to do that to get it working.

Comment: in Web8 or prior?

Comment: In any version since it was introduced. I only recall the GloballyAcceptedClaims being needed on the server side and the website isn't the server in this case -- the content service is. I don't know, maybe there's something about your setup that's different from mine.